# Slow Postgres performance with in clause

Tags: performance, postgresql, select, postgresql-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have a quiet simple query:

```
SELECT
  contract.ctrId,
  contract.ctrNr
FROM
  changeLog,
  contract
where
  changelog.entid in (select contract.ctrid from contract where contract.ctrnr LIKE '1000002%');
```

This query takes 800 ms.

If I change the query with the inner select clause to the result of the select (which is a single number)

```
SELECT
  contract.ctrId,
  contract.ctrNr
FROM
  changeLog,
  contract
where
  changelog.entid in (100000001611624);
```

This query only takes 16 ms.

The inner select executed alone takes 4 ms.

Chnagelog.entid has an index. Contract.ctris id a primary key. The contract table has just 2 rows the changelog table has about 40 thousand.

Still I really cannot get my head around this. What can be the problem with the inners select?

Comment: Have you looked at/compared the query plans?

Comment: Questions about performance require proper information. Please consider instructions in the tag info for [postgresql-performance].

Comment: Before worrying about performance, I think you should fix your query. You have not specified a join condition so therefore you are getting a cartesian join...every record in contract is being joined to every record in changeLog. That may not be a big problem in this particular case since contract only has 2 records, but in general it's bad practice (unless it's intentional).

Comment: Could you post both results from EXPLAIN ANALYZE at http://explain.depesz.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for providing not enough details, I will be more precise and follow the tag descriptions next time.

The join of changelog and contract did not have much effect on performance.

The problem here was that changelog is a VIEW. It is a union of changelogActive and changelogPendig tables. Postgres needed to join the two tables in the view on every select.

Thank you guys all for the hints, you helped a lot!